# Laravel AJAX - Remember multiple chosen filters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been trying to solve this for the past few weeks. I can't just get my head around it.

On my webpage I have four filters in total: one search, filter by year, filter by launch-site and filter by country. These filters work perfectly on their own. They manage to quickly filter my database and return the results I need.

The issue lies the fact that if apply one filter and then decide to apply another filter, it resets the first filter. The AJAX call I am making, simply does not have the capability to remember what my first filter I applied was. From my research I have found out that I need to somehow save the filters the user chooses and apply them with a button or something. I think that would be the easiest way to implement this.

Basically, what we want to achieve is to allow the user to choose multiple filters, without the first one getting reset.

This is the code I am currently using for my AJAX call:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filter-type').select2();
  $('#filter-year').select2();
  $('#filter-pad').select2();
  $('#search').on('keyup', function() {
    $value = $(this).val();
    delay(function() {
      if ('#search'.length > 3) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: '{{$operatorname->spadoc_cd}}',
          data: {
            'search': $value
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#data-holder').html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    }, 300);
  });
  $("#filter-pad").change(function() {
    $value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "{{$operatorname->spadoc_cd}}",
      data: {
        'search': $value,
        type: 'site'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#data-holder').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
  $("#filter-type").change(function() {
    $value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "{{$operatorname->spadoc_cd}}",
      data: {
        'search': $value,
        type: 'object_type'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#data-holder').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
  $("#filter-year").change(function() {
    $value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "{{$operatorname->spadoc_cd}}",
      data: {
        'search': $value,
        type: 'launch_year'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#data-holder').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
if ($request->ajax())
    {
        $output="";
        $operatorsatellite = DB::table('satellites')
            ->where(function($q) use ($request) {
                if(empty($request->type) && empty($request->rocket_type)) {
                    $q->orWhere('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('country','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('object_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
                } else {
                    if(!empty($request->type)) {
                        $q->orWhere($request->type,'LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
                    }
                    if(!empty($request->site)) {
                        $q->orWhere('site','LIKE','%'.$request->site.'%');
                    }
                    if(!empty($request->object_type)) {
                        $q->orWhere('object_type','LIKE','%'.$request->object_type.'%');
                    }
                    if(!empty($request->launch_year)) {
                        $q->orWhere('launch','LIKE','%'.$request->launch_year.'%');
                    }
                }
            })
            ->where('country', $spadoc_cd)->Paginate(700);
        if ($operatorsatellite)
        {
            foreach ($operatorsatellite as $key => $operatorsatellites) {
            $output .='<div class="table-row" id="launchsatdisplay">'.
                    '<div class="satname">'.'<a href=/satellite/'."$operatorsatellites->norad_cat_id".'>'.$operatorsatellites->satname.'</a>'.'</div>'.
                    '<div>'.'<div class="satnumbers">'.'<span>'.$operatorsatellites->norad_cat_id.'</span>'.'<span>'.$operatorsatellites->object_id.'</span>'.'</div>'.'</div>'.
                    '<div>'.$operatorsatellites->object_type.'</div>'.
                    '</div>';
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
    else {
        $operatorsatellite = DB::table('satellites')->Paginate(50);
        return view('pages/operator-filter', compact('operators', 'operatorsatellite', 'searchsite', 'searchyear', 'searchtype'));
    }
```

Comment: why don't you store your filters in session when you send ajax request?

Comment: @skileton - I actually never thought of that. That seems like a good idea! I guess the first step is to find out on how to implement it. Would you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: @skileton There is no question mark between each query in the URL. How would you go about fixing that?

Answer (score 2):

I updated my answer because it wasn't the best way to do it and not correct at all.
first, you can just send your filters in `GET` data(and in your situation it will be more sensible then use sessions), in your ajax call add that filters as parameters (if they were selected or typed, depends on your input) something like this

```
data: {
   'filter-1': $('.myInput1').val(), // take value from filter 1 and send them as get params
   'filter-2': $('.myInput2').val(), // take value from filter 2 and send them as get params
   // ...........
}
```

so your url should be like this `mydomain.me/myurl?search=someValue?filter-1=somevalue1&filter-2=somevalue2`

if you want to update data on every select change, take the value from other filter also, so they will not be lost, for example

```
 $("#filter-type").change(function() {
$value = $(this).val();
$value2 = $('otherFilter2').val();
$value3 = $('otherFilter3').val();
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "{{$operatorname->spadoc_cd}}",
  data: {
    'search': $value,
    'filter2' $value2,
    'filter3' $value3,
  // other code ....
```

so from this url you can get filters and use them in your query.

then check if value exists in your php code

```
if(!empty($request->filter-1)) {
   $q->orWhere('someData','LIKE','%'.$request->filter1.'%');
}
```

and do the same on others. of course you can use sessions, but there's no point to do that, send data as `GET` parameters will be easier and better way

Comment: sorry, im typing from mobile, not able to write the whole code to help you

Comment: What would I replace the `filter-1` with that is in your question? I managed to get the Javascript part to work, but cannot get the PHP part to work. Thanks!

Comment: the problem is in your ajax call. for example `$("#filter-type").change(function() {...` on each request you are taking value only from one select and send it(all other filters are empty, cause you didn't send them), when it gets to php, all your `$request->something` will be empty apart from `$request->type`, and after that you override your html. when you trigger your on change event, you should also provide other filters values(if they selected), also move your on change events in one function, avoid duplicating code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155704/discussion-between-skileton-and-d-777klm).